# iOS JavaScript support for timedMetadata

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video, http-live-streaming, http-streaming

I'm looking for information on the availability to read timedMetadata or even just the ID3 tags from streaming video in a HTML5 container on the iOS platform.

The Media Player framework has for instance the MPTimedMetadata class to read the information in native apps.  Though the documentation for MPTimedMetadata claims a JavaScript implementation is available I've not been able to find any information on it, even after going over the Webkit source.

Does anyone have any experience with the metadata via JavaScript in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that Apple needs to support, according to this post: http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?14702-New-iOS-streaming-supports-timed-data-event-in-live-and-video-on-demand-streams/page2&highlight=javascript

Although I really would like to be proven wrong!